# Reward videos number of plays limit

Tags: android, admob, reward

I am developing one android game. I am planning to integrate a reward videos in my app. I am planing to go for AdMob mediation. Below is my question.

User can watch a reward video to save his/her life in game. So s and when he/she out, I will show them msg to watch a video and continue. **My question is, how many videos I can show to the user?** I know we can set the impression and hourly limit in admob dashboard. But still is there any restriction on showing reward ads per day? **What if user keep watching the ads many times ?**

Thanks you in advance

Comment: There is a limit in reward ads,I think it is 20 video/day, depends on your application download it may increase

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CLIFFORDPY

Comment: Do you know where can I see the info about this limits?